# Рабочие примеры взаимодействия с VK API

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, авторизация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, рабочий пример либо на JavaScript, либо на PHP, где были бы реализованы авторизация в VK, получение списка друзей, например, и отправка сообщения. Собрать это в кучу пока не получается.

Не посылайте на сообщество разработчиков ВКонтакте: я там уже был.

Есть ли готовые примеры кода?

Answer (score 5):

Роман, вам никак не пропустить подробное чтение [документации](https://vk.com/dev) – там **не** сообщество разработчиков, а ваш основной ресурс, чтобы вообще что-то сделать с ВКонтакте.

Подробнее по вашим вопросам:

1. [авторизация ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/dev/authentication) – там три вида;
2. авторизация **не нужна** для [получения списка друзей](https://vk.com/dev/friends.get) – просто открываете ссылку вида `https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=XXXXXX`, где XXXXXX – целое число, ID пользователя, чьи друзья нужны. Напр. для Павла Дурова это 1. Ответ - в формате json;
3. а вот [отправка сообщения](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send) требует регистрации т.н. [Standalone (мобильного) приложения](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile) и получения токена. Так что спамить не получится.
4. [пример работы с Javascript](https://vk.com/dev/Javascript_SDK) есть (по кускам) в JS SDK.
5. на php просто [используйте cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) для выполнения http запросов как в п.2.

Answer (score 1):

Авторизация http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=1659